# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException Pleas help me

Tags: java, arrays, exception, out

i have a Problem with my Java Code. I tried everything to figure out whats the issue for the error. Maybe you can help me out.

```
public static void Convert1() throws IOException,ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException,NumberFormatException {
    String csv ="/Users/Max/IdeaProjects/Download/Asset1.csv";
    BufferedReader br = null;
    String line = "";
    String csvSplitBy = ";";

    File file = new File ("/Users/Max/IdeaProjects/Download/Datum1.csv");
    if (file.exists()) {

    } else {



        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csv));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {


              String[] asset = line.split(csvSplitBy);


            String[] Date = {asset[0]};  //Datum
            String[] Open = {asset[1]};  //Öffnungskurs
            String[] High = {asset[2]};  //Tageshoch
            String[] Low = {asset[3]};  //Tagestief
            String[] Close = {asset[4]};  //Schlusskurs
            String[] Volume = {asset[5]};  //Handelsvolumen


            // Es werden die Dateien geschrieben die die einzelnen Teilbereiche enthalten
            BufferedWriter BW = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("Datum1.csv", true));
            StringBuilder SB = new StringBuilder();
            for (String element : Date) {
                SB.append(element);
                SB.append(";");
            }
            BW.write(SB.toString());
            BW.close();

            BufferedWriter BW2 = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("Öffnungskurs1.csv", true));
            StringBuilder SB2 = new StringBuilder();
            for (String element : Open) {
                SB2.append(element);
                SB2.append(";");
            }
            BW2.write(SB2.toString());
            BW2.close();

            BufferedWriter BW3 = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("Tageshoch1.csv", true));
            StringBuilder SB3 = new StringBuilder();
            for (String element : High) {
                SB3.append(element);
                SB3.append(";");
            }
            BW3.write(SB3.toString());
            BW3.close();

            BufferedWriter BW4 = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("Tagestief1.csv", true));
            StringBuilder SB4 = new StringBuilder();
            for (String element : Low) {
                SB4.append(element);
                SB4.append(";");
            }
            BW4.write(SB4.toString());
            BW4.close();

            BufferedWriter BW5 = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("Schlusskurs1.csv", true));
            StringBuilder SB5 = new StringBuilder();
            for (String element : Close) {
                SB5.append(element);
                SB5.append(";");
            }
            BW5.write(SB5.toString());
            BW5.close();

            BufferedWriter BW6 = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("Handelsvolumen1.csv", true));
            StringBuilder SB6 = new StringBuilder();
            for (String element : Volume) {
                SB6.append(element);
                SB6.append(";");
            }
            BW6.write(SB6.toString());
            BW6.close();
        }

    }

}
```

Everytime i want to run i get the following Exception.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at ConvertCSVtoArraysAsset1.Convert1(ConvertCSVtoArraysAsset1.java:30)

Maybe you could help me with that.

greetings

Comment: As you can see we don't have line numbers here. Perhaps you could tell us which line 30 is.

Answer (score 0):

By the only place where you've used array indices and the '1' in your exception, the error is probably on this line:

```
String[] Open = {asset[1]};
```

And that's probably because there are not those many elements in your array.

Put this line after your String.split to see what your array is made up of, and it's length:

```
System.out.println( Arrays.toString( asset ) );
```